The Last node in Autodesk Viewer is always material#
Im exporting SVF from 3DS max and loading it into the Autodesk viewer, or forge viewer. The nodes in the graph show the names of the objects as they appear in 3d studio. However instead of the last name in the hierarchy being my mesh, it always shows as the material. Why? I have seen many other examples that are not like that. 
